# Can we have multiple google custom searches for images in a single page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api, google-custom-search

What if I wanted to do 2 different searches with different results in a page? I tried to duplicate this code but to change the new term but I only get results from the first query:

```
    var termS = "Paris";
    var date = "1500";
    $.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1", {
        q: termS + " in " + date,
        alt: "json",
        searchType: "image",
        cx: "MY_CX",
        key: "MY_API",
        rights: "cc_publicdomain",
        filter: "1",
        num: "10",
        fileType: "jpg",
        imgType: "photo"
    },
    function (data) {
        $.each(data.items, function(i,item){    
            $(".my_images ul").append('<li><img class="img-responsive" src="' + item.link + '"></li>');
        });
    });
```

Comment: So there is an exact replica of this code snippet on the same page  and that doesn't work ? how do you know only the 1st one worked and not the 2nd ?

Comment: I know it because if I duplicate the code only the first show me images. Basically I need to run it twice just with different q= "termS..."

Comment: While the script looks OK, the reason i wanted to confirm is if you see network activity (2 requests or just 1) in devetools. The other question would be appending to the same list with `.my_images` class.

Comment: @Searching I have 2 requests. Just imagine the code above, repeated but with a different q= termS, what would you expect is 2 different results. yet no, it doesn't. I believe google doesn't let you make 2 request, maybe if you use 2 different keys but I only have one. The other solution maybe is by using an iframe. But it's a dirty hack